# How to do Statistical hypothesis testing

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, statistical-inference, sampling, hypothesis-testing

Let $\Omega$ be the finite sample space and random variable $X$ is defined on $\Omega$ sending $x$ to $x$. The probability distribution function of $X$ is denoted by $f(x;p_1,..p_r)$ where $p_i$ are parameters.

Given a sequences $S=\{a_{i}\}_{i=1}^{n}$ where $a_{i} \in \Omega$, I want to know whether this sequence is sampled according to that probability distribution $(\Omega,f(x))$ or not.

For example $\Omega = \{0,1\}$,
\begin{eqnarray}f(x;p)=
\begin{cases}
p, &x=0\cr 1-p, &x=1 \cr 0, &otherwise\end{cases},
\end{eqnarray}
$p=0.1$,$n=10$,$S=0100100011$, Then how to do Statistical hypothesis testing ?

Comment: Are $a_i$s independent?

Comment: @Calculon  I don't know whether they are independent or not. To make this problem simple, it seem that we always have such assumption.

Answer (score 1):

We expect that the sequence has more or less one zero, because the xpectednumber  zeros is $10\cdot 0.1=1$. Since there are six zeros in your example we have the null hypothesis $H_0: p\leq 0.1$. And the corresponding alternative hypothesis is $H_1: p>0.1$

We need a significance level. Let´s say it is $\alpha=0.05$

The confidence level is $1-\alpha=0.95$. The random variable for the number of zeros in the sequence is binomial distributed, with $n=10$ and $p=0.1$ The sample is not sufficently large enough to approximate the binomial distribution by the normal distribution.

Thus we have to find the greatest  value of $x$ where

$$\sum_{i=0}^{x} {10 \choose i} \cdot 0.1^i\cdot 0.9^{10-i}<0.95$$

Not many attempts has to be made to find that $x=2$.

The interval for not rejecting $H_0$ is $\{0,1,2\}$. The interval for rejecting $H_0$ is $\{3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}$

Therefore we have to reject the null hypothesis at a signicance level of $5\%$. If the sample would have no ones up to two ones we could not reject the null hypothesis. But with this sample we have to reject the null hypothesis.

Comment: Thanks. This do help! But in fact, I want to do it in general. Then should I replace the left hand side of the inequation by the cumulative distribution function of $X$ ? Can you explain the idea in short? Thanks again.

Comment: @zongxiangyi The LHS is the cdf of $X$. To get it in a more general way you  replace $0.1$ by $p$,  $0.9$ by $(1-p)$ and $10$ by $n$. And on the RHS you replace $0.95$ by $1-\alpha$. If $n>30$ then you can replace the LHS by $\Phi\left( \frac{x+0.5-n\cdot p}{\sqrt{n\cdot p\cdot (1-p)}} \right) $ (normal approximation).

Comment: A better rule of thumb for approximation of the binomial distribution is $n\cdot p\cdot (1-p) >9$